# Apache Solr query to get the document if matching criteria satisfy for n number of occurrences

Tags: solr, solr4

I want to create a solr alert with this scenarios. I have a raw file with fields and value as:

```
{
  {
    id: 123XX,
    event:Item Purched from amazon.com,
    time: 1:00:00 AM
  },
  {
    id:234XX,
    event: Item Purchased from flipkart.com,
    time: 1:00:30 AM
  },
  {
    id:117x,
    event: Item Purched from flipkart.com,
    time: 1:00:30 AM
  },
  {
    id:118x,
    event: Item Purched from amazon.com,
    time: 1:00:35 AM
  },
  {
    id:101XXX,
    event: Item Purched from amazon.com,
    time: 1:00:38 AM
  }
}
```

What i want to achieve is get the record if there's 3 matches found for [Item Purched] and [amazon.com] in time span of one minute. If not, then none of the records should be returned.

Comment: Do you want to find out if this has happened within a particular minute, or do you want to find the minute timestamps where this has happened? Only for amazon, or for any event type? `event` is the only field that should be grouped? What have you tried?

Comment: Within a particular minute and For any event type . Basically i want a grouping on (item id) 1st token and (amazon.com ) second token

Comment: If you want to group by those fields, you'll _usually_ want to preprocess the content, so you have a field containing "[Item Purchased]" and "amazon.com" separately. That way you can use faceting and filtering to get what you want, without having to run multiple functions on each document and string each time you're querying. In this case - the string could probably be considered an identifier by itself (since it'll be identical for the same item + domain), so faceting based on `event` with mincount set to `3` should give you the valid entries.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh